# Given value for cosine of an angle calculate cosine of half of an angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have a cosine value of an angle $α$. I would like to calculate the cosine value corresponding to half of the angle $α$. For example if $cos(α) = 0.5$, I would like to know what cos(α/2) is equal to. Is this possible to calculate without using the inverse cosine function, diving the resulting angle by two, and calculating the cosine again?

Comment: Hint. Look up the formula for $\cos (2\theta)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) & \Rightarrow \cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \cos(2x) = 2\cos^{2}(x) - 1\\\\
& \Rightarrow \cos(x) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is a cosine half-angle formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$$\left(2\cos\frac{\theta}2\right)^2=\left(1+\cos\theta\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\right)^2\\
\Longrightarrow 4\cos^2\frac{\theta}2=2+2\cos\theta\\
\Longrightarrow \cos\frac{\theta}2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}2}$$

1. If $\quad0\leq\theta\leq\pi\quad$, take positive.
2. If $\quad\pi\leq\theta\leq2\pi\quad$, take negative.